# python3 manage.py runserver for Django

Tags: python, django, settings, manage.py

I can't run Django server and this is the problem :

```
MacBook-Pro-di-viv:vivsite viv$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 121, in import_module
raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.settings'
```

I had this problem after this Python command line:

```
>>> settings.configure()
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I asssume that your settings file is called ".settings.py".

Did you try to rename it without starting by "." ?

Comment: Thanks for your aswer! My settings file is called "settings.py" yet